# Google Colab zone

Tags: google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I need to find out to place my dataset in GCS in the same zone so that I avoid charges when running training on TPU's and reading large datasets from GCS.

Does anyone know how to find out current Google Colab instance zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data should be stored in a bucket that is in the same zone as the *Cloud TPU* (or the same region if that specific zone isn't available); to the best of my knowledge Colab itself doesn't play a role in the situation.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I need to know how to find out the specific Colab instance's zone or region, ir order to copy my data to a bucket in the same zone. Do you know if there is any command I can run that outputs the zone/region of the GCE VM Colab is running on?

Comment: I think we are on the same page, but just to be absolutely clear for the sake of future readers, I think you are concerned about the location of the Cloud TPU that you are accessing via Colab, not the location of the Colab instance (ie the VM it is running on) - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Assuming that _is_ true, [this thread](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/597#issuecomment-502746530) contains a comment from the Colab team indicating that all instances are in the US. That comment is over a year old now, so it might be worth checking with them again if possible. If you can confirm that's still true, then based on the chart [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/types-zones) it seems safe to assume that you are somewhere in us-central.

Failing that, I'm not sure that there is a way to read the zone directly from a Colab TPU, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I think what matters is what the Cloud TPU zone is, and not the zone the VM the Colab instance is running on. But since 2019, as your link indicates, it seems currently TPU's are available in most zones/regions. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Running (within Colab)

```
!curl ipinfo.io
```

You get something similar to

```
{
  "ip": "3X.20X.4X.1XX",
  "hostname": "13X.4X.20X.3X.bc.googleusercontent.com",
  "city": "Groningen",
  "region": "Groningen",
  "country": "NL",
  "loc": "53.21XX,6.56XX",
  "org": "AS396XXX Google LLC",
  "postal": "9711",
  "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

Which tells you *where* you Colab is running.